# Do we really need a process alive 24/7 to listen to messages in a RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I am new to `RabbitMQ`, went through some of the tutorials.  All of the samples were an infinite loop listening on messages. Much like what sockets do. My question is, Why can't we have a simple .NET DLL sitting in some folder and when a message arrives that concerns my dll, RabbitMQ should create an appdomain, add that DLL, invoke the proper method and destroy the appdomain? Can't we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well RabbitMQ is not related to .NET, so RabbitmQ cannot "create appdomain and add dll there". To receive messages from rabbit service, you need somehow connect to it. After that you have to persist that connection to be able to receive incoming messages. So at minimum you have connected to rabbit service with some code (with official .NET client for example) and you have persisted connection. Now you received a message. Of course you can create new app domain, load dll there, invoke some method in dll and destroy app domain, but you can imagine how ugly and inefficient it is. You already have that message and can process it, so why load other dlls? Not to mention rabbit is often used for high-rate message processing, and your method kills all performance (without any reason). All in all you can write your own .NET application which will do what you describe, but that is not "simple" way.

Comment: I do not have high volume of messages. And I was hoping for RabbitMQ to have a feature to load-n-invoke on its own so I don't have to keep a process in memory all the time. Your answer is precise and betters my understanding of RabbitMQ. Thankyou

Comment: Even if that was the case - that process which will load-n-invoke your dll will have to be in memory all the time instead :)

Comment: Well, I figured the RabbitMQ has a process running 24/7 all the time already. Why not it spawns a thread that invokes an external dll

Comment: RabbitMQ _server_ might have such process, but we are talking about client here. Client (which is almost always located on the other machine) does not have any processes unless you start one yourself. And of course server process cannot invoke any external dlls on new message - it's just nonsense. It's _server_ after all.